# Error using ajax to check email from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've read the answers from several users here, and my intention is to check if the email is already on the DB.

So my code is the following

```
**HTML CODE**
<div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                      <input id="fnam" name="firstname" class="profile-input form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" maxlength="25" required />

                     <!-- <input id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required="" type="text">-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
            <!-- Prepended text Last Name-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                      <input id="lastname" name="lastname" class="profile-input form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off" maxlength="25" required />
             <!-- <input id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required="" type="text">-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <!-- Prepended text Email-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                      <input id="email" name="email"  class="profile-input form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50"  required/>
            <!-- <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text">-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

JS/ AJAX

```
 function chemail(inputText) {
 var email1 = $("#email").val();
 var x = document.forms["myappForm"]["email"].value;
 var datastring = '$email='+ x; // get data in the form manual



 //var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  


    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf("."); 

// if(inputText.value.match(mailformat)){

  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {

var msgp="Invalid Email. Ex: abc@ggggg.com";
    document.getElementById("msgreturn").style.color= "red";
     document.getElementById("msgreturn").innerHTML = msgp;
      document.getElementById("lem").style.color= "red";
document.myappForm.email.focus();  


return false;  
}  


else  
{  
 document.myappForm.email.focus();  
 var msgp="Email verified";
    document.getElementById("msgreturn").style.color= "green";
     document.getElementById("msgreturn").innerHTML = msgp;
      document.getElementById("lem").style.color= "green";

return true;  


$("span.loading").html("<img src='images/ajax_fb_loader.gif'>");
        $("span.validation").html("");
        var datastring = '&email='+ x;
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", // type
                    url: "check_email.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
                    data: datastring, // post the data
                    success: function(responseText) { // get the response
                        if(responseText == 1) { // if the response is 1
                            $("span.email_val").html("<img src='images/invalid.png'> Email are already exist.");
                            $("span.loading").html("");
                        } else { // else blank response
                            if(responseText == "") {
                                $("span.loading").html("<img src='images/correct.png'> You are registred.");
                                $("span.validation").html("");
                                $("form input[type='text']").val(''); // optional: empty the field after registration
                            }
                        }
                    }
                                    } 
 }
```

and the check_email.php

```
<?php require_once("../../php_includes/dbconnect.php"); 

$email = $_POST['x']; 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT 'email' FROM 'members' WHERE 'email' = '$email'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {  echo '1'; } else {  echo '1'; } 

?>
```

So the sources are all working, I've set some alerts inside of ajax but it didn't worked, can you please tell me where am I making the mistake , I'm following the example from other users from this site, however can't reach a solution.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump( $_POST['x']);`?

Comment: Also, you `echo '1'` whether it finds 1 row or not. How can you tell the result? Is it possible there are more than one rows with the email address?

Comment: On my database it's not possible at the moment , I just have 3 registries, and var_dump don't retrieve anything,check_email.php doesn't retrieve anything

Comment: but it doesn't appear any 404, or error on console

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have directly copied your code, the error can be found by checking indentation.  I would suggest, BTW, that you make your editor replace tabs with spaces, as tabs may not show the spacing correctly on any other system (such as SO!).

```
function chemail(inputText) {
  var email1 = $("#email").val();
  var x = document.forms["myappForm"]["email"].value;
  var datastring = '$email='+ x; // get data in the form manual



  //var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  


  var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf("."); 

  // if(inputText.value.match(mailformat)){

  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {

    var msgp="Invalid Email. Ex: abc@ggggg.com";
    document.getElementById("msgreturn").style.color= "red";
    document.getElementById("msgreturn").innerHTML = msgp;
    document.getElementById("lem").style.color= "red";
    document.myappForm.email.focus();  

    return false;  
  }  

  else

  {  
    document.myappForm.email.focus();  
    var msgp="Email verified";
    document.getElementById("msgreturn").style.color= "green";
    document.getElementById("msgreturn").innerHTML = msgp;
    document.getElementById("lem").style.color= "green";

    return true;  

   // HERE'S THE PROBLEM!!! The following code never gets executed.  Missing parenthesis.

    $("span.loading").html("<img src='images/ajax_fb_loader.gif'>");
    $("span.validation").html("");
    var datastring = '&email='+ x;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", // type
      url: "check_email.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
      data: datastring, // post the data
      success: function(responseText) { // get the response
        if(responseText == 1) { // if the response is 1
          $("span.email_val").html("<img src='images/invalid.png'> Email are already exist.");
          $("span.loading").html("");
        } else { // else blank response
          if(responseText == "") {
            $("span.loading").html("<img src='images/correct.png'> You are registred.");
            $("span.validation").html("");
            $("form input[type='text']").val(''); // optional: empty the field after registration
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  } // <--- this parenthesis is in the wrong place.
```

Another thing that should tip you off to the problem is to use the Network tab in the web console.  You can use this to see the traffic between the browser and the server; in this case, you would find that there was no request made to the PHP script.

---

Addendum:

I believe `datastring` should be an object, not an url encoding.  In other words,

```
var datastring = {email: x};
```

where `x` = `$('#email').val();`

For what it's worth, since you're using JQuery for your ajax, it would be more concise to change things like

`document.getElementById("msgreturn").style.color= "red";` to `$('#msgreturn').css('color','red');`

Comment: I've changed like you mentioned however, it still dont appear on network the check_email.php

Comment: I'm not sure what event is supposed to trigger your ajax.  I didn't pay much attention past the misplaced parenthesis.  I don't see any `$(document).ready(function(){ ...` which is where event listeners should be.  Break the problem down into solvable parts:  figure out how to trigger an event, then put your ajax in the event and figure out how to make the ajax work.  Eat the elephant one bite at a time.